# Pivot table in Python for time series data

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, time-series, pivot-table

How can I use pivot table to summarize weather data?

I have time series data including year, month and day. I want yearly data by summing specific months only, i.e. august to november.

My dataframe should look like this

[image]

Comment: `help( pandas.pivot_table )` has a great explanation and nice examples. I would recommend that as the starting point. If you're still having trouble, show us the code and explain what you tried, so that you can get help. Your question as it is right now has no specific answer and is not really suitable for stackoverflow :)

Comment: I dont think you need a pivot table for this. Just get your precitpiation data into a dataframe with a DateTimeIndex. Then resample as desired (probably you want monthly), and aggregate that resampled series (probably you want sum). Then if you want separate columns for year and month, compute those from the DateTimeIndex